# Strapi /auth/local api throws 500 error for wrong password or email not confirmed

Tags: strapi

Strapi Version: 4.11.4
Operating System: Windows 11
Database: Postgress
Node Version: 14.19.1
NPM Version: 6.14.16

I am having an issue when I try to log in with the wrong password or not confirmed account or blocked account I am getting 500 error as an internal server error instead of a message in response. but I can see an error on strapi console please can anyone give me fix for it i also updated strapi version but still same old version strapi was 4.7.0

i tried updating strapi and i want messages in response intead of 500 error

Comment: Did you figure out the reason?